# Jquery auto increase number when click

Tags: jquery

I want use +1 for increase number of votes in system , te idea it´s add 1 by each user i use this code :

```
<a onclick="increase_n(1)" href="#">Add 1</a> 

<script>
function increase_n(size)
{
var size_ini=15;
var size_increase=size_ini+(++size);
$(".content").css("font-size",""+size_increase+"px")
}
</script>
```

I don´t know how auto increase the number when i go and do click other time , the idea it´s increase the number in each click , in one click give 11 other click give 12 other 13 , etc

Regards !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the badge showing process like it will increase badge value to 1 when you click,
Use this

```
 var size_ini = 15;
    function increase_n(size) {
        var size_increase = size_ini++;
        alert(size_increase);
        $(".content").html("<span>" + size_increase + "</span>")
    }
```

Yout HTML should be like this:

```
<a onclick="increase_n(1)" href="#">Add 1</a>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
```

**DEMO HERE**

http://jsfiddle.net/2LkYK/

Comment: And for decrease what i need , regards !

Comment: Simply minus Size variable like this:

var size_increase = size_ini--;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to increase the font size by 1 at each click. You could do something like this :

```
<a onclick="increase_n()" href="#">Add 1</a> 

<script>
function increase_n()
{
 var currentSize = parseInt($(".content").css("font-size"),10);
 $(".content").css("font-size",++currentSize+"px");
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = 15;

function increase_n(increment)
{
    size += increment;
    $(".content").css("font-size", size + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your anchor an id or class:

```
<a id="anchor" href="#">Add 1</a>
```

Then use jQuery to increase your `font-size`:

```
$("#anchor").click(function(){
    var fs = $('#anchor').css('font-size');
    $(this).css('font-size', (parseInt(fs, 10) + 1) + 'px');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CEqty/